# ARKit uses "UIView" as contents in "SCNNode"

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an odd problem, or maybe what I am doing is odd.

I have an ARKit app that displays a SCNNode with a data view embedded when a barcode is detected.  When the data view is tapped I want to detach it from the node and add it as a subview to the main view.  When tapped again I want to re attach it to the SCNNode.

I found [this code](https://github.com/erikhric/ar-menu) that does at least part of what I want.

My app works well the first time.  The data appears in the SCNNode:

```
{
    let transform = anchor.transform
    let label = SimpleValueViewController(nibName: "SimpleValueViewController", bundle: nil)


    let plane = SCNPlane(width: self.sceneView.bounds.width/2000, height: self.sceneView.bounds.height/2000/2)  //was sceneView

    label.update(dataItem.title!, andValue: dataItem.value!, withTrend: dataItem.trend)
    label.delegate = self

    plane.firstMaterial?.blendMode = .alpha
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = label.view //self.contentController?.view

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.opacity = 0.75
    planeNode.simdPosition = float3(transform.columns.3.x + ( base * count), 0, transform.columns.3.z)
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    childControllers[label] = planeNode
    label.myNode = planeNode
    label.parentNode = node

    if("Speed" == anchorLabels[anchor.identifier]!) {

        let constraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
        planeNode.constraints = [constraint]
    }  
    count += 1
}
```

`SimpleValueViewController` has a tap recognizer that toggles between being a subview and being inside the node.

Here is the problem.

It comes up fine.  The view is inside the node.

When tapped it gets attached to the main view.

When tapped again the node just shows a white square and taps no longer work.

I finally gave up and recreate a new viewController, but it still occasionally fails with only a white square:

Here is the code to detach/attach  It is pretty messy as I have been pounding on it for a while:

```
func detach(_ vc:Detachable) {

    if let controller = vc as? SimpleValueViewController {
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview();
        self.childControllers.removeValue(forKey: controller)
        let node = controller.myNode
        let parent = controller.parentNode
        let newController = SimpleValueViewController(nibName: "SimpleValueViewController", bundle: nil)
        if let v = newController.view {
            print("View: \(v)")
            newController.myNode = node
            newController.parentNode = parent
            newController.update(controller.titleString!, andValue: controller.valueString!, withTrend: controller.trendString!)
            newController.delegate = self
            newController.scaley = vc.scaley
            newController.scalex = vc.scalex
            newController.refreshView()

            let plane = node?.geometry as!  SCNPlane
            plane.firstMaterial?.blendMode = .alpha
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = v
           // newController.viewWillAppear(false)
            newController.parentNode?.addChildNode(newController.myNode!)
            newController.attached = false;
            self.childControllers[newController] = node
        }  
    } else {
        print("Not a know type of controller")
    }
}

func attach(_ vc:Detachable) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let controller = vc as? SimpleValueViewController {
        self.childControllers.removeValue(forKey: controller)
        let newController = SimpleValueViewController(nibName: "SimpleValueViewController", bundle: nil)
        let node = controller.myNode
        let parent = controller.parentNode

        let scaleX = vc.scalex!/self.view.frame.size.width
        let scaleY = vc.scaley!/self.view.frame.size.height
        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        newController.view.transform = transform
        newController.myNode = node
        newController.parentNode = parent
        newController.update(controller.titleString!, andValue: controller.valueString!, withTrend: controller.trendString!)
        newController.delegate = self
        newController.scaley = vc.scaley
        newController.scalex = vc.scalex
        node?.removeFromParentNode()
        self.childControllers[newController] = node

        newController.attached = true

        self.view.addSubview(newController.view)
    } else {
        print("Not a know type of controller to attach")
    }
    }
}
```

I was thinking it was a timing issue as loading a view from a nib is done lazily so I put in a sleep for 1 second after the SimpleValueViewController(nibName: "SimpleValueViewController", bundle: nil) but that did not help.

Anything else I can try? I am way off base?   I would like not to have to recreate the view controller every time the data is toggled.

Thanks in Advance.

Render functions:

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

// func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

// updateQueue.async {

```
//Loop through the near and far data and add stuff

let data = "Speed" == anchorLabels[anchor.identifier]! ? nearData : farData
let base = "Speed" == anchorLabels[anchor.identifier]! ? 0.27 : 0.2 as Float
print ("Getting Node for: " + self.anchorLabels[anchor.identifier]!)
var count = 0.0 as Float
for dataItem in data {
    let transform = anchor.transform
    let label = SimpleValueViewController(nibName: "SimpleValueViewController", bundle: nil)


    let plane = SCNPlane(width: self.sceneView.bounds.width/2000, height: self.sceneView.bounds.height/2000/2)  //was sceneView

    label.update(dataItem.title!, andValue: dataItem.value!, withTrend: dataItem.trend)
    label.delegate = self

    plane.firstMaterial?.blendMode = .alpha
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = label.view //self.contentController?.view

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.opacity = 0.75
    planeNode.simdPosition = float3(transform.columns.3.x + ( base * count), 0, transform.columns.3.z)
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    childControllers[label] = planeNode
    label.myNode = planeNode
    label.parentNode = node

    if("Speed" == anchorLabels[anchor.identifier]!) {
        let constraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
        planeNode.constraints = [constraint]         
    } 
    count+=1
}
```

and update

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

    guard currentBuffer == nil else {
        return
    }
    self.updateFocusSquare(isObjectVisible: false)
    // Retain the image buffer for Vision processing.
    self.currentBuffer = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage
    classifyCurrentImage() 
}
```

ClassifyCurrentImage is where the barcode recognizer lives.  If a barcode is found it adds an anchor at the spot in the scene.

Comment: How is the code in the renderer functions?

Comment: edited to add code.

Comment: I using xib and load it to a UIView and it works for me